# Set cookie only for one tab browser in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

How can I set cookie for each tab of browser separately? I have application in MVC 5 with logging users.
Problem:
I logged e.g. in FireFox to app in first tab, then in second tab I logged as other user. After that I refresh first tab and I see information from second user. But I want to have two tab with two logged different users. How can I do that? Thanks.
Here is part of code to set cookie:

```
 FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), false, userData);

                string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
                Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Cookies are set at browser/application level.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to open new FF window, but still no changes.

Comment: Ok, thanks all for responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a way of doing this with just cookies, as the browser will always send the cookies it has for the domain when making a request.

You could add a hidden field or a URL param with a unique session ID, that combined with the cookie for auth should let you determine if a user has multiple tabs open, or force a login if the token isn't provided along with the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two browsers (eg. FF & Chrome) or two domain names for the application on the serwer side. I think there is no browser with windows (or tabs) dependent cookie engine.
Maybe you should create your own tools for your purpose :)